# How to sum all the values in an array in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have this document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7948fc9a0d0e5ca78aa886"),
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5e76c896eebef71b39aa8277"),
    "user_qty" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5e76c997eebef71b39aa827a"),
            "qty" : 20
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5e794aa19a0d0e5ca78aa887"),
            "qty" : 40
        }
    ],
    "price" : 20,
    "reviews" : [
        {
            "name" : "Pablo Perez",
            "comment" : "Me quedan muy bien!"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Corina Smith",
            "comment" : "Muy nice"
        }
    ],
    "location" : {
        "street" : "La Bonita",
        "city" : "Caracas",
        "country" : "Venezuela"
    }
}
```

I would like to make a query that returns the sum of all the quantities (qty) in the array `user_qty`. 
In this document, it would be `20 + 40 = 60`. Any help?

Comment: What have you attempted? Please share any code in text with your attempts and the specific error you are obtaining, also I suggest reading [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to achieve this quite simply.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalQty: {
        $sum: "$user_qty.qty"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you need only total (and not original fields), replace [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#addfields-aggregation) by [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation)

[Try it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tmbDRhOVz80)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was searching for